# Why is chi square used when creating a confidence interval for the variance?

Tags: confidence-interval, variance, chi-squared-distribution

This is a very basic question. Why do we use a chi square distribution? What is the meaning of this distribution?
Why is this the distribution used for creating a confidence interval for the variance?

Every place I google for an explanation just presents this a fact, explaining when to use chi, but not explaining *why* to use chi, and why it look the way it does.

Many thanks to anyone that can point me towards the right direction and that is - really understanding why I am using chi when I am creating a confidence interval for the variance.

Comment: You use it because - when the data are normal - $Q = (n-1)\frac{s^2}{\sigma^2}\sim \chi^2_{n-1}$. (This makes $Q$ a pivotal quantity)

Comment: See also http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15711/confidence-of-a-variance-estimate and its links.

Comment: For those who are interested in the applications of or further research into $\chi^2$, you will want to pay attention to the distinction between a $\chi^2$ ("chi-squared") distribution and a $\chi$ ("chi") distribution (it is the square root of a $\chi^2$, unsurprisingly).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## **Quick answer**

The reason is because, assuming the data are i.i.d. and $X_i\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, and defining
\begin{eqnarray*}
\bar{X}&=&\sum^N \frac{X_i}{N}\\
S^2 &=& \sum^{N} \frac{(\bar{X}-X_i)^2}{N-1}
\end{eqnarray*}
when forming confidence intervals, the sampling distribution associated with the sample variance ($S^2$, remember, a random variable!) is a chi-square distribution ($S^2(N-1)/\sigma^2 \sim \chi^2_{n-1}$), just as the sampling distribution associated with the sample mean is a standard normal distribution ($(\bar{X}-\mu)\sqrt{n}/\sigma \sim Z(0,1)$) when you know the variance, and with a t-student when you don't ($(\bar{X}-\mu)\sqrt{n}/S \sim T_{n-1}$).

## **Long answer**

First of all, we'll prove that $S^2(N-1)/\sigma^2$ follows a chi-square distribution with $N-1$ degrees of freedom. After that, we'll see how this proof is useful when deriving the confidence intervals for the variance, and how the chi-square distribution appears (and why it is so useful!). Let's begin.

### The proof

For this, maybe you must get used to the chi-square distribution in this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution). This distribution has only one parameter: the degrees of freedom, $\nu$, and happens to have a Moment Generating Function (MGF) given by:
\begin{equation*}
m_{\chi^2_\nu}(t)=(1-2t)^{-\nu/2}.
\end{equation*}
If we can show that the distribution of $S^2(N-1)/\sigma^2$ has a moment generating function like this one, but with $\nu=N-1$, then we have shown that $S^2(N-1)/\sigma^2$ follows a chi-square distribution with $N-1$ degrees of freedom. In order to show this, note two facts:

1. If we define,
   \begin{equation*}
   Y = \sum \frac{(X_i-\bar{X})^2}{\sigma^2} = \sum Z_i^2,
   \end{equation*}
   where $Z_i\sim N(0,1)$, i.e., standard normal random variables, the moment generating function of $Y$ is given by
   \begin{eqnarray*}
   m_Y(t) &=& \mathbb{E}[e^{tY}]\\
   &=&\mathbb{E}[e^{tZ_1^2}]\times \mathbb{E}[e^{tZ_2^2}]\times ...\mathbb{E}[e^{tZ_N^2}]\\
   &=&m_{Z_i^2}(t)\times m_{Z_2^2}(t)\times ...m_{Z_N^2}(t).
   \end{eqnarray*}
   The MGF of $Z^2$ is given by
   \begin{eqnarray*}
   m_{Z^2}(t) &=& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(z)\exp(tz^2)dz\\
   &=&(1-2t)^{-1/2},
   \end{eqnarray*}
   where I have used the PDF of the standard normal, $f(z)=e^{-z^2/2}/\sqrt{2\pi}$ and, hence,
   \begin{equation*}
   m_Y(t)=(1-2t)^{-N/2},
   \end{equation*}
   which **implies that $Y$ follows a chi-square distribution with $N$ degrees of freedom**.
2. If $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent and each distribute as a chi-square distribution but with $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ degrees of freedom, then $W=Y_1+Y_2$ distributes with a chi-square distribution with $\nu_1+\nu_2$ degrees of freedom (this follows from taking the MGF of $W$; do this!).

With the above facts, note that if you multiply the sample variance by $N-1$, you obtain (after some algebra),
\begin{equation*}
(N-1)S^2 = -n(\bar{X}-\mu)+\sum(X_i-\mu)^2,
\end{equation*}
and, hence, dividing by $\sigma^2$,
\begin{equation*}
\frac{(N-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}+\frac{(\bar{X}-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2/N}=\sum \frac{(X_i-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2}.
\end{equation*}
Note that the second term in the left-side of this sum distributes as a chi-square distribution with 1 degree of freedom, and the right-hand side sum distributes as a chi-square with $N$ degrees of freedom. **Therefore, $S^2(N-1)/\sigma^2$ distributes as a chi-square with $N-1$ degrees of freedom**.

### Calculating the Confidence Interval for the variance.

When looking for a confidence interval for the variance, you want to know the limits $L_1$ and $L_2$ in
  \begin{equation*}
 \mathbb{P}\left(L_1\leq \sigma^2 \leq L_2\right) = 1-\alpha.
 \end{equation*}
 Let's play with the inequality inside the parenthesis. First, divide by $S^2(N-1)$, 
  \begin{equation*}
\frac{L_1}{S^2(N-1)}\leq \frac{\sigma^2}{S^2(N-1)} \leq \frac{L_2}{S^2(N-1)}.  
  \end{equation*}
 And then remember two things: (1) the statistic $S^2(N-1)/\sigma^2$ has a chi-squared distribution with $N-1$ degrees of freedom and (2) the variances is always greather than zero, which implies that you can invert the inequalities, because\begin{eqnarray*}
 \frac{L_1}{S^2(N-1)}\leq \frac{\sigma^2}{S^2(N-1)} &\Rightarrow& 
 \frac{S^2(N-1)}{\sigma^2}\leq \frac{S^2(N-1)}{L_1},\\
 \frac{\sigma^2}{S^2(N-1)} \leq \frac{L_2}{S^2(N-1)} &\Rightarrow& 
 \frac{S^2(N-1)}{L_2} \leq \frac{S^2(N-1)}{\sigma^2},\\
 \end{eqnarray*}
 hence, the probability we are looking for is:
  \begin{equation*}
 \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{S^2(N-1)}{L_2} \leq \frac{S^2(N-1)}{\sigma^2}\leq \frac{S^2(N-1)}{L_1}\right) = 1-\alpha.
 \end{equation*}
 Note that $S^2(N-1)/\sigma^2 \sim \chi^2(N-1)$. We want then,
 \begin{eqnarray*}
  \int_{\frac{S^2(N-1)}{L_2}}^{N-1}p_{\chi^2}(x)dx &=& (1-\alpha)/2\ \ \ ,\\
  \int_{N-1}^{\frac{S^2(N-1)}{L_1}}p_{\chi^2}(x)dx &=& (1-\alpha)/2\ \ \,
 \end{eqnarray*}
 (we integrate up to $N-1$ because the expected value of a chi-squared random variable with $N-1$ degrees of freedom is $N-1$) or, equivalently,
 \begin{eqnarray*}
  \int_{0}^{\frac{S^2(N-1)}{L_2}}p_{\chi^2}(x)dx=\alpha/2,\\
  \int_{\frac{S^2(N-1)}{L_1}}^{\infty}p_{\chi^2}(x)dx=\alpha/2.
 \end{eqnarray*}
 Calling $\chi^2_{\alpha/2}=\frac{S^2(N-1)}{L_2}$ and $\chi^2_{1-\alpha/2}=
 \frac{S^2(N-1)}{L_1}$, where the values $\chi^2_{\alpha/2}$ and $\chi^2_{1-\alpha/2}$ can be found in chi-square tables (in computers mainly!) and solving for $L_1$ and $L_2$,
 \begin{eqnarray*}
  L_1 &=& \frac{S^2(N-1)}{\chi^2_{1-\alpha/2}},\\
  L_2 &=& \frac{S^2(N-1)}{\chi^2_{\alpha/2}}.
 \end{eqnarray*}
 Hence, your confidence interval for the variance is
 \begin{equation*}
 C.I.=\left(\frac{S^2(N-1)}{\chi^2_{1-\alpha/2}},
 \frac{S^2(N-1)}{\chi^2_{\alpha/2}}\right). 
 \end{equation*}

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. However my question is much more basic: why is (S2(N−1)/σ2 the statistic and not S2? Why is this statistic with a Chi square distribution? What is the meaning of this?

Comment: Simply because $S^2$ does not follow a centered chi-square distribution, while $S^2(N-1)/\sigma^2$ does and, therefore, its easier to work with. Are you asking for a derivation for that? (i.e., you want someone to show you that $S^2(N-1)/\sigma^2$ follows a chi-square distribution with $N-1$ degrees of freedom?)

Comment: It would be helpful to modify this answer to include the *very strong* but unstated assumption that the sample variance follows a chi-squared distribution when the underlying data are *independent* and follow a *normal* distribution. Unlike the theory of the distribution of the sample mean, where in practice its sampling distribution will be *approximately* Normal to reasonable accuracy in many situations, this same asymptotic behavior tends not to happen with the sample variance (until sample sizes become extremely large).

Comment: Oops. So, so true! This actually came from a problem solution that I handed out to some students, where I state on the question all these assumptions. I edited the answer now.

Comment: even more basic than that. I'm asking for an explanation of chi square distribution. And also, why does S2(N−1)/σ2 follow a chi-square distribution with N−1 degrees of freedom?

Comment: @user34756: do you mean a description like "a chi-squared distribution is the distribution of the sum of squared drawings from a stanard normal distribution (with as many drawings as degrees of freedom)"?

Comment: Ok, I added a proof.

Comment: @user34756 The reason we don't use the distribution of $S^2$ directly is that its distribution depends on the value of a parameter. You may find it useful to investigate the use of pivotal quantities in constructing confidence intervals.

Comment: Isn't $f(z) = e^{-z^2/2}$ instead of $f(z) = e^{-z^2}$ ?

Comment: Yeah, you are right; typo corrected there, thanks.