# Can you derive the distribution of the Gaussian variance estimator without using moment generating functions?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, variance, moment-generating-function

Given a dataset of Gaussian i.i.d. $X_i's$, we can show that the maximum likelihood estimates for this Gaussian distribution's mean and variance are given as: 
\begin{align}
\hat{\mu} &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n} X_i  \\[10pt]
\widehat{\sigma^2} &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (X_i - \hat{\mu})^2
\end{align}
We can easily tell that $\hat{\mu}$ will be Gaussian distributed as it is a linear function of Gaussian random variables. But the same cannot be said for $\widehat{\sigma^2}$ as it is a non-linear function of $X_i's$. My question is, what is the best way to determine the variance estimator's distribution for arbitrary $n$?

For the case where $n = 2$ we have:
\begin{align}
\hat{\sigma} &= \frac{1}{2}\left( \big(X_1 - \frac{1}{2} \left( X_1 + X_2 \right)^2 \big) + \big(X_2 - \frac{1}{2} \left( X_1 + X_2 \right)^2 \big)\right)  \\[10pt]
\widehat{\sigma^2} &= \frac{1}{4} \left( X_1^2 + X_2^2 - 2X_1X_2 \right)
\end{align}
Even for this case it is not exactly clear to me how to go about determining the estimator's distribution analytically.

Comment: When the $X$'s are Gaussian, the variance will be distributed as chi-squared. Cf: [Why is chi square used when creating a confidence interval for the variance?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/76444/7290)

Comment: So working with moment generating functions or characteristic functions would be the best way to solve for the distribution? Is there a treatment of going about it without using MGFs? Although I imagine it's unwieldy, I'd be interested in seeing how one might attempt it.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to prove that $$S^2=\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X})^2\sim \chi^2_{n-1}$$without the mgf. This comes from [the property](https://www.statlect.com/probability-distributions/normal-distribution-quadratic-forms) that, if $Z$ is a $n$-dimension Normal random vector, $Z\sim\text{N}(0,I_n)$ and if $A$ is an $n\times n$ symmetric and idempotent matrix, then 
$$\xi^2=Z^\text{T} A Z \sim \chi^2_{\text{tr}(A)}$$
where $\text{tr}(A)$ denotes the trace of $A$. (The [proof](https://www.statlect.com/probability-distributions/normal-distribution-quadratic-forms) of this result does not necessarily involves the mgf.) Since
$$S^2=\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X})^2=Z^\text{T} A Z$$when
$$A=I_n-\frac{1}{n} \mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^\text{T}$$and $A$ is idempotent with $n-1$ eigenvalues equal to $1$ and one equal to $0$ (with eigenvector $\mathbf{1}$), the above lemma applies and$$S^2\sim\chi^2_{n-1}$$