# Is it possible to have a point estimate outside of confidence interval?

Tags: probability, confidence-interval, point-estimation

Is it possible to have a point estimate outside of confidence interval? Could anyone give me an example?

Comment: Presumably with the qualification that the point estimate and the CI are estimating the same quantity. Otherwise, the answer is obviously yes.

Comment: Just a few hours ago a nice example was posted at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/271845.  As the confidence narrows, this particular interval converges to the median of an asymmetric distribution, while the estimate itself is made at the mean of that distribution.  Consequently, for a sufficiently small confidence the estimate must lie outside the confidence interval.