# Standard deviation of errors

Tags: r, regression, error

I have a multiple regression model (information derived from gretl):

$$Y=‐3,859921 \ln(P)
+
1,707514\,
(A)
+
3,578656$$

$$\quad\quad\space(1,216387)\quad\quad\quad(1,259650)\quad\quad(0,323867)$$

the standard errors of the parameter estimates are underneath.

How to calculate the standard deviation of errors?

I really appreciate your answers!!!

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by a "standard deviation of errors"?

Comment: Thx for your answer! By standard deviation of errors I mean: the stdev of the error terms of the two parameter $P$ and $A$

Comment: do the answers to this question apply? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7004/calculating-required-sample-size-precision-of-variance-estimate/7008#7008