# The Unknown Variances in Sample Size Calculation for Two Proportions vs Means

Tags: t-test, sample-size

I recognize that the sample size calculation for the two-sample test at $\alpha = 0.05$ and $\beta = 0.80$ under a normal distribution becomes:

$$
n_{i} = \frac{16 * \sigma^2}{\Delta^2}
$$

But, what is in variance in the context of proportion vs mean measures? If the experiment was an AB experiment, can I assume that the variance is derived from the variance of the current population?

I've also seen that $\sigma^2$ in a proportion test also becomes $\sigma_{1} + \sigma_{2} = p_{1}(1-p_{1}) + p_{2}(1-p_{2})$. But, when the test is a comparison of means, how do you know what's the appropriate variance?

Answer (score 1):

The variance estimate for comparing means between 2 groups is the variance within each group. (The standard 2-sample t-test assumes that both groups have the same within-group variance, although [Welch's t-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test) relaxes that assumption.)

So you need to have a reliable estimate of that variance to estimate your sample size reliably. If you don't have such an estimate from your knowledge of the subject matter and the literature, a pilot study can help. Unfortunately, [estimates of variance themselves have high variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/7004/28500), so you need to be conservative when working from a small pilot study.